# vue.js Uri dynamic Templating

Tags: vue.js

I' m trying to achieve dynamic Uri templating in vue

Data :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     "navigation": [
        {
          "url": "https://domainxxx.org/{param1}",
          "param1": "John",
          "param2": "123"

        },
        {
          "url": "https://otherdomain.org/{param2}",
          "param1": "Other",
          "param2": "43213432143214"

        }
        ]
  }})
```

Code:

```
<div id="app">
 <template v-for="row in navigation">
 <br/>
  <a  :href="row.url"> Hello </a>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 </template>
</div>
```

For this example expected link (href)

- https://domainxxx.org/{param1}   > https://domainxxx.org/John
- https://otherdomain.org/{param2}   > https://otherdomain.org/43213432143214

Is there any option to do templating during binding property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using computed properties + any templating engine or simple string concatenation.

BUT, in your example I don't se any pattern between two urls, can you tell me why you want to parametrize these?

EDIT:
Ok, got this ;)
You need to store unique url templates. So in this case I would add url extraction method:

```
methods: {
  getUrl: function(navigation) {
    return TemplateEngineOfYourChoice.Template(navigation.url, navigation);
  }
}

<a  :href="getUrl(row)"> Hello </a>
```

Comment: Thank You that solved this, post some additional answear

Answer (score 1):

DonMateo's answer is correct: you need to use a custom method that renders the url for each row. Here I use Mustache, but you can use a template language of your choice:

```
Mustache.tags = ['{', '}'] // Using custom delimiters, since the default is {{ }}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     "navigation": [
        {
          "url": "https://domainxxx.org/{param1}",
          "param1": "John",
          "param2": "123"

        },
        {
          "url": "https://otherdomain.org/{param2}",
          "param1": "Other",
          "param2": "43213432143214"

        }
        ]
  },
  methods: {
    getURL: function(row) {
       return Mustache.render(row.url, row)
    }
  }
})
```

And the template:

```
<a :href="getURL(row)"> Hello </a>
```

Comment: For each row there is different uri template for example for first one there is row.url+ row.param1 for second row.url +row.param2  for third row.url + row.username  + row.oherparam + row.otherparam2

Comment: So how do you decide which uri template will be used? If you have it in mind, you can use `v-if`: `<a v-if="your condition" :href="your desired url>`

Comment: uri tempalte is from database there are houndreds of houndres of different templates

Comment: Thank You, in mean time i've found some other 2 solution 
 for just template posting belowe

Answer (score 0):

Jst to have complete answear
Thank you @donMateo I will accept your answear because it lead me to solve this. Im not sure at the moment what is best method use computed poperty or function, function was easier so posting solution.

So answear is to use function

```
<a  :href="getUrl(url,data)"> Hello </a>
```

This is a case when we have dynamic  url tempalte for each object

Ive found two ways for doing templating
- https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/uri-template.html
and
some custom code that solve my case

```
 getUrl: function (url,data)
        {
            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var key = keys[i];
                url = url.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, data[key]);
            }
            return url;

        }
```